# comparing two numbers in an array to see if they equal in javascript

Tags: javascript

so I'm creating a matching game, here is my click listener:

```
let clicked = -1;
var values = [];

//on click listener function for squares
var box_clicked = function(box){
box.addEventListener("click", function(){
    clicked = clicked + 1;

    //HERE ARE THE VALUES THAT I WANT TO COMPARE
    var value = this.innerHTML;
    values.push(value);
    if(clicked === 2){
        twoClicked();
    }
    console.log(clicked);
    $(this).addClass("fade z-index");
 });
}
```

So when clicked equals 2 and the twoClicked() function is called this code runs:

```
var twoClicked = function(){
    $("div").removeClass("fade z-index");
    clicked = 0;
    var third_value = values.pop(2);
    console.log(values);

    var x = values.indexOf(0);
    var y = values.indexOf(1);
    alert(x);// this alerts -1 for some reason
    alert(y);// this alerts -1

    //if x and y equal then alert "A MATCH"

    values = [];
    values.push(third_value);

}
```

If I alert x or y it returns -1, why isn't it giving me the value of the two boxes that i clicked.

[check out the game here](https://enightengale.github.io/matching_game/)
if you want the full code check it out [here](https://github.com/enightengale/matching_game)

Comment: The [`.indexOf()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) returns the index at which the specified value first appears in the array, or returns -1 if the value isn't in the array. Presumably the values 0 and 1 aren't in the array. If you want to get the value from indices 0 and 1 use `values[0]` and `values[1]`. It would be helpful if you could [edit] the question to show the relevant HTML directly in the question body, so that we can see what values you're pushing.

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks for that input! I never knew it returned -1 if there wasn't anything in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) function returns the index of the first element where the value is found. It returns -1 if the value is not found in the array.

This code

```
var x = values.indexOf(0);
```

...will return the index of the first element that contains 0. if none of the elements is set to 0, it returns -1.

If you want the value of the element at index 0, just use this:

```
var x = values[0];
```